# SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet - Search Results

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a Suitlet that is performing a search for a list of results. When I execute the script, the results of the search are returned no problem. However, when other users try to execute the script the search does not return any results (even other Admin users). The deployment is set to Execute as Admin and Released, All Roles is checked on the Audience tab and role is not part of any script logic. Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading an existing search through `search.load()`, make sure the search is Public.
Go the definition of your search, tick the `Public` checkbox on the main page.